# Unique Color Detection and Storing images dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

If an image is given , find out the unique colors in that image and write output images corresponding to each unique color.
In that all other pixels which don't have that unique color should me marked white.

for eg , if an image has 3 colors - in the output folder there should be three images where each color is separated. Using Open CV & Python.

I've created the unique color list using my methods. What I want is to give a count of all those unique colors in the sample.png image and give the corresponding images output as per the question.

Comment: Then you should write a program to do that.

Comment: My apologies for the comment above. Please don't take that to be representative of the stackoverflow community as a whole. If you could include a sample picture and what code you have so far it would help us understand and solve your issue.

Comment: I wrote a kmeans classification code to detect the colors. But while returning the the images I was getting only the black or the white background. Although I worked it out myself. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below (with comments) should help you with this!

Feel free to follow up if any of the code is unclear!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from copy import deepcopy

# Load image and convert it from BGR (opencv default) to RGB
fpath = "dog.png"  # TODO: replace with your path
IMG = cv.cvtColor(cv.imread(fpath), cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Get dimensions and reshape into (H * W, C) vector - i.e. a long vector, where each element is a tuple corresponding to a color!
H, W, C = IMG.shape
IMG_FLATTENED = np.vstack([IMG[:, w, :] for w in range(W)])

# Get unique colors using np.unique function, and their counts
colors, counts = np.unique(IMG_FLATTENED, axis=0, return_counts = True)

# Jointly loop through colors and counts
for color, count in zip(colors, counts):

    print("COLOR: {}, COUNT: {}".format(color, count))
    # Create placeholder image and mark all pixels as white
    SINGLE_COLOR = (255 * np.ones(IMG.shape)).astype(np.uint8)  # Make sure casted to uint8

    # Compute binary mask of pixel locations where color is, and set color in new image
    color_idx = np.all(IMG[..., :] == color, axis=-1)
    SINGLE_COLOR[color_idx, :] = color

    # Write file to output with color and counts specified
    cv.imwrite("color={}_count={}.png".format(color, count), SINGLE_COLOR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ack, he beat me to it. Well, here's what I've got.

Oh no, I don't think the line

```
blank[img == color] = img[img == color]
```

behaves how I think it does. I think it just coincidentally works for this case. I'll edit the code with a solution I'm more confident works for all cases.

Original Image

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("circles.png");

# get uniques
unique_colors, counts = np.unique(img.reshape(-1, img.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True);

# split off each color
splits = [];
for a in range(len(unique_colors)):
    # get the color
    color = unique_colors[a];
    blank = np.zeros_like(img);
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, color, color); # edited line 1
    blank[mask == 255] = img[mask == color]; # edited line 2

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Blank", blank);
    cv2.waitKey(0);

    # save each color with its count
    file_str = "";
    for b in range(3):
        file_str += str(color[b]) + "_";
    file_str += str(counts[a]) + ".png";
    cv2.imwrite(file_str, blank);
```